# how to run S3 placed python code in Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have multiple python scripts(test1.py, test2.py, test3.py) which I already uploaded on S3 bucket(test_s3_bucket) inside the scripts directory.

scripts/test1.py

```
def abc():
  return "function abc"
```

scripts/test2.py

```
from test1 import abc
def xyz():
  t1 = abc()
  return "function xyz > {}".format(t1)
```

Now I need to run those python code(stored in s3 bucket) through Lambda Function.

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  test2_obj = s3.download_file("test_s3_bucket", "script/test2.py", "/tmp/test2.py")
return test2_obj.xyz()
```

But I am facing issue when I run the lambda function

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xyz'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "requestId": "exxxxxxx-bxxe-4xxd-bxx1-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 4, in lambda_handler\n    test2_obj.xyz()\n"
  ]
}
```

If this is not a correct approch, could you please suggest which approch will be good to use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Lambda developer guide shows you how to package your code as a zip file.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html

Individual files aren't loaded from S3.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, we can achieve it 2 different ways.

1st using **"upload from" S3 or .zip** where we will put our all dependency with lambda code in single package so that we can access all dependency parallely.

2nd using layers with versioning.

but in my scenario I will create multiple lambda function for different operation and those dependency library is use by all lambda function so in that case Layers is a better choice.